# Run TestNG.xml through command prompt

Tags: maven, selenium

I am trying to run testng.xml from command prompt and getting error that main class not found.
How to give reference of org.testng.jar while running testng.xml from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)?

> Assuming that you have TestNG in your class path, the simplest way to invoke TestNG is as follows:
>
> ```
> java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]
> ```

If you have your tests and [testng.jar](https://testng.org/doc/download.html) in your [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) the above command should be enough.

Approximate syntax for more complex scenarios:

```
java -cp "/path/to/test.jar;/path/to/your/tests.jar;/path/to/test/dependencies.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

where `testng.xml` is the [TestNG config file](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)

More information with examples: [Automated test using TestNG](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG) chapter